# Why does my full node need to load IP addresses from DNS seeds on restart?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, p2p, dns

I stop one of my Bitcoin Core full nodes (v0.19.1) with 10 connections and then start it again. It needs to load IP addresses from DNS seeds. Why is this? Why doesn't it try the addresses of peers it was connected to prior to the shut down? Are they not persisted in addrman? It could then obtain more IP addresses through gossiping from those peers and not need to keep going back to the DNS seeds.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/16939 and this https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/15434 but will look into more before attempting an answer.

Comment: And this Bitcoin Core PR review club: https://bitcoincore.reviews/16939

Comment: What do you see in the debug.log that indicates it is using the DNS seeds?

Comment: "Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.emzy.de" etc followed by the other DNS seeds. Then "277 addresses found from DNS seeds" and "dnsseed thread exit"

Comment: Do you have the same problem with v0.21.0?

Comment: No I haven't been able to replicate on v0.21.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be resolved for me in v0.21 with this merged [PR 16939](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/16939) and some additional context in this [issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/15434) and this Bitcoin Core PR [review club](https://bitcoincore.reviews/16939).

Falling back to load IP addresses from DNS seeds should be the last resort and as you say addresses of previous peers should be persisted in addrman after stopping bitcoind and restarting.